# What threads are used on Avid BB5 barrel adjusters?

Tags: disc-brake, fastener

I thought I might replace the locknut on my front brake barrel adjuster because the current knurled one needs pliers where it sits in an awkward place behind the mudguard stays.  But it's an unusual thread.  It's bigger than M6, but it's 1mm pitch (or 25tpi) An M6 screw seems to engage the female thread but pulls straight out.

Their *in-line* barrel adjuster uses M6 threads, and I could fit one of those when I re-cable anyway, locking off the one on the brake - but I don't plan on replacing the cables just yet.

Comment: I've ordered some M7x1 nuts to try out, so we'll soon have an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They did indeed turn out to be M7 (1 mm pitch).

Nuts are fairly easy to get, but at least the locknuts (half nuts) I bought take an 11 mm spanner.   None of my multitools, or any I can find online, have this size spanner built in; even my workshop spanner set omits it, but in over 20 years of building and maintaining hardware for work and play, this is probably the first time I've handled M7 parts.

Comment: I still want to switch to hex nuts, and my reserve tyre lever is steel.  I feel some precision angle-grinding coming on

Comment: For what it's worth, I have never tightened a barrel adjuster lock nut. I have even been known to remove the locknuts altogether to gain more adjustment range and save a gram. The tension of the cables keeps the adjusters from adjusting themselves just fine. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @BetterSense I've often found front brake adjusters to creep, and the BB5s I've got on there are moderately fussy about cable length.  I'm a little picky as well, because one of my gear cables unscrews itself, and the other screws itself in, meaning I lose my lowest gears